# Return StreamBuilder data to a Stack

Tags: flutter, listview, stream-builder

I am trying to return a Firestore collection back to a StreamBuilder within Flutter which has the child element of a Stack.

The expected result is

[image]

But I am being presented with the following error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#2fd30 relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib/widgets/task_list.dart:63
```

StreamBuilder with ListView and Stack

```
StreamBuilder _buildOfferCount(task) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: DatabaseService.bidCount(task),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        _bids = snapshot.data?.size?.toString() ?? '0';
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(_bids);
        }
        return Row(children: [
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: int.parse(_bids),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // return Text(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  Tasker tasker = Tasker.fromDoc(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.7 * 12 * index),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 16,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage(tasker.profileImageUrl),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          radius: 14,
                        ),
                      ));
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Is the `StreamBuilder` inside a Column?

Comment: no its inside of a row when its called

Comment: This part of the code doesn't seem to have any problem on its own. Without seeing the full layout code is a little hard to tell. It's probably the case that somewhere along the line there is an unbounded widget and it needs to wrapped in a `SizedBox`, `Expanded` or `Flexible` to solve the issue.